# enable-update-delete-insert a row when radio buttons pressed

Tags: oracleforms

I had tabular with 10 number of display items which is disabled update delete insert property and also the text_items so at initialization of form most likely are disabled. I tried to add radio button so when user select a row only selected row will be enabled its
text_items and update delete insert property when user move to another record
it will disabled again but I am getting this error message

> ORA-00904: "RADIO_GROUP33": invalid identifier

```
SELECT ROWID,column1,column2,column3,RADIO_GROUP33 FROM table1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for sharing my problem that I was navigating through multiple forms using 
`OPEN_FORMS` which is by default has `NO_SHARE_DATA_LIBRARY` I had replace it with 
`CALL_FORM` which is has same parameters as `OPEN_FORMS` but it is allow forms to do update insert and delete transactions for more understanding Please refer to oracle forms  builder help search for `OPEN_FORM` AND `CALL_FORM` key words

Thanks